# How to develop windows 10 uwp on real device (mobile)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to debbuging my app on real device (lumia 830 with windows 10 mobile 10.0.10581.0) 
Developer Mode is ON on both devices (mobile and PC), but when i'm trying to emulate app on my device  I've got an error (DEP6100 and DEP6200). However i can easily emulate on emulators and my PC. Can't understand what's the problem.

Has anyone been able to successfully deploy a UWP app on phone and debug it?
How to register your phone for development for Windows 10 mobile?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I faced the same problem yesterday and I solved applying this:

- Create a Registry Key in: **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SirepClient]** (Probably you will need to create it)
- Create a `dword` with name `"DisableProtocol3"` and value `00000001`
- Restart Visual Studio and try deploying the solution back again.

[image: Registry]

**IMPORTANT**: It's a provisional solution meanwhile a patch is included in Windows 10 mobile. We will have to consider deleting this key after that.

Solution found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/ea4e016c-2ea6-4b2c-b507-dcc91b31c904/probleme-lancement-application?forum=winstoreappsfr).

Comment: Yesterday afret update of W10 on my desktop it turned out that those DEP errors appeared. I've modified the registry basing on your answer and it's working. Though I cannot give you second +1. Thanks.

Comment: @Romasz you're welcome :) I'm really pleased to know I'm helping people

Comment: @eva FP Your fix worked!  I was having problem with WP 10.0.10581.0 and your solution is working well!  Question: How did you find this solution?

Comment: @DeanB_Develop I'm glad to know it :) I found it by chance in a French MSDN question. I let the link in the solution but I thought it was better to translate it.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround! You can also do this from an admin command prompt: `reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SirepClient /v DisableProtocol3 /t REG_DWORD /d 1`

Comment: @Chris Schmich that makes it much easier!

Comment: Why does this work? Does this work by breaking something else? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem few days ago. It turned out that Emulators and SDK version must match the Insider preview build on your device.

Try to download both of them: [emulators and SDK from here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview), in my case it worked like a charm.

As for registering device for developement - [it's not needed any more](http://www.windowscentral.com/all-windows-10-devices-developer-unlock-mode). Starting from Windows 10 all devices have 'developer unlock' in settings.

Comment: When i trying to download a new emulators, the latest is 10.0.10563.0..... but latest is 10.0.10581.0, seems like i should wait for a new emulator :c

Comment: @AndrewZabarowski I've downloaded emulators and sdk with the same number as you have mentioned and in my case everything started working. I'm not sure if MS releases emulators and sdk for every insider build. So - finally have you managed to run app on your device or the emulators and sdk haven't helped?

Comment: i download both sdk and emulator 10.0.10563.0, and i've still got a DEP6100 and DEP6200, cant understand whats the problem. Something strange.

Comment: @AndrewZabarowski Then try to do few more things: 1) try different USB port and cable, 2) unplug the phone, click on a tray where you safely remove devices in WIndows (near the clock), open devices and settings, find your phone and uninstall it, plug the phone it will install once again, try, 3) if that haven't helped, there is one more thing - reset phone to factory defaults (Settings -> System -> Information -> Reset), after reset don't forget to turn developer unlock. There is a chance that it can help. You may also uncheck my answer as it haven't solved the problem :)

Comment: Trying to debbug on emulator 10.0.10563.0 got an error "Failed to load SKU "WP":There is an error in XML document(22,7)". Cant understand whats the problem oh..seems like need to hard reset, if i want to debbug on real device :c

Comment: @AndrewZabarowski Seems like the problem you have described [is mentioned here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b31fc5d0-c3e1-4b0f-b62c-cfc26765601a/xde-10563-preview-wouldnt-launch?forum=microsoftdeviceemu).

Comment: @EvaFP I guess you already have tried to download newest apis and reset your phone to factory defaults?

Comment: Yes i did it, I finally found a weird workaround... I attach what I did in a solution

Comment: @EvaFP Seems like couple of things may produce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by development environment, such as VS version, SDK version, etc. Please update your SDK version and phone OS version to the latest one, and I recommend you to use VS2017 to develop Windows 10 apps. I have met this problem when I used VS2015.