# How to install Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 on Win 10 mobile phone

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to remote debug my uwp app on a Win 10 mobile phone device.
How does one install the remote debugging tools on the phone?

Directly installing the rtools_setup_x64.exe via File Explorer does not work, error "Something went wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not to install remote tools. Just enabling 'developer mode' (Settings > For developers > Use developer features) and deploy your uwp app by using Visual studio.

[image]

Comment: I was looking for an alternative to deploying from VS 2015 because this does not work with all of my machines: "DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available".

Comment: I have the same problem and the developer mode *IS* activated on my phone. It's very frustrating!

Comment: About DEP6200/6100 Error: Have you tried this one?  ->   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473200/

Comment: I have my phone in developer mode but I can't still run the debugger - it say's "The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging." Any idea how to solve that?