# Cordova Debug Build Error: DEP6100, DEP6200

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm unable to build the default BlankCordovaApp on a Window Phone 10 device OS build `10.0.10581.0`.

I get the following error when trying to debug (Debug > Windows Phone 10 > Device) [image]

Note. I am using `Node.js 0.12.7` (ia32), Cordova tools `5.3.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
[How to develop windows 10 uwp on real device (mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473200/how-to-develop-windows-10-uwp-on-real-device-mobile) by @Eva FP

The problem is specific to with Window Phone `10.0.10581.0`

- Create a Registry Key in: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SirepClient] (Probably you will need to create it)
- Create a dword with name "DisableProtocol3" and value 00000001
- Restart Visual Studio and try deploying the solution back again.