# Visual Studio "Pin is required to establish a connection"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting a weird error from Visual Studio after a fresh install on a clean system.

Today my computer was getting groggy so I decided to reinstall the computer (Win10) this is exactly what I did

1) Backed up using a batch program I wrote which compresses the dragged on directory using 7zip and renames it "folders name( dd/mm @ hh:mm)", creates 2 txt files with data for ftp commands, opens an ftp connection to my webserver, uploads the zip, then uploads to same zip to my nas and then to my sd card, the batch deletes the zip from temp and the text files, everything said it performed normally.

2) I went to reset my pc and reset everything and deleted all files

3) After Reinstalling I downloaded 7zip and visual studio with all the addons in the tick box list at the beginning of the installation, except I noticed it has windows phone 10 emulators this time.

4) unzipped my work from the SDHC

5) Opened in VS, VS asked me to login so I did everything loaded in normally

6) Plugged In my phone (Lumia 930 WP10) clicked start debugging

and I got this popup

```
A PIN is required to establish a connection with the remote device. Please enter the PIN to pair the Device
```

I have never seen this error, and as far as I can tell no one else has, that's why I have written in detail what I did to get it, the only post I can find says it is in the debugging properties so to set it to no authorisation but that is for a raspberry pi using VS and that option is not there or anywhere within VS

the phone does not have a pin, or can I find a single setting anywhere on the phone or VS.

I did however come across a setting in the phone that allows you to connect to your phone in the browser on a computer via its ip and remotely control the phone and access all the data via the browser

[The Error I Get in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hL3E.png)

[The Phone Remote from a browser (If anyone is curious)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6C9u.png)

UPDATE*** no matter what I do, I CAN run any of the windows phone 10 emulators, but VS CANNOT detect any emulators other than 8.1 emulators

Comment: if I click project --> myapp properties --> no debugging option just "Debug" --> no authentication options

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGa1K.png

Comment: Is developer mode enabled in the phone?

Comment: Yes it is, I used it for debugging just before I reinstalled the computer

Comment: Same issue here, i tried pairing using the PIN provided by the phone in the dev page in settings but it still fails.

Comment: Try my solution @Rafael

Comment: @BillieGallagher I can't change the authentication Mode! What to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED**

I went to programs & features, clicked visual studio community edition, and clicked repair, after it finished it said there was a problem installing the windows 10 SDK (v XX.XX.XX), so I went to

https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-sdk

I noticed the version number on the website to be higher, so I installed the SDK manually using the download link and presto it works :)

Comment: Hello, that actually worked. It looks like Visual Studio Installation is bad. I installed VS 2015 enterprise with Update 1 when this problem started happening. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: This solution with the re-installation doesn't help for me. I re-installed Visual Studio (Community Edition) and the SDK but I still get prompted for a PIN. It doesn't matter what I enter (the PIN the device shows me or Cancel) the deployment is interrupted with an error message :-(

Comment: @llasarov any hope with a solution ? I have the same problem till now

Comment: @OXXY I figured out that my problem was caused by VMWare Fusion, since I've had my development environment in a virtual machine running on a MacBook.
After setting up a new PC with the same development environment (Visual Studio version, Win 10 SDK, etc.) the problem disappeared.
My impressin is that the virtual machine has had an impact on the USB protocol. And since Visual Studio is using USB to communicate with the device, the connection was somehow impacted.

Comment: That's is totally fair enough to kill my dreams ! Thank you so much for your comment really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, then I found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667162

The solution is really helpful for me.

Simply, you can do this from an admin command prompt:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SirepClient /v DisableProtocol3 /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when running Visual Studio in a virtual machine under both VM Ware Workstation 12 on a windows host, and VMWare Fusion 8 on a MAC host.

The solution was to edit the virtual machine settings and change the USB Compatibility settings from version 3.0 to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the following steps:

1. Turn the developer mode off on the phone and switch to "Only install Apps from Store"
2. Unplug the phone's USB connection
3. Restart the phone
4. Restart your PC
5. Start Visual Studio
6. Connect the phone to your USB port
7. Try to debug the app on your phone, if Visual Studio does say anything else than "You have to put the phone into Sideload mode" (or simular), start over with step 1.
8. Put the phone into sideload mode (not developer mode) and try again to debug, now the same message should show up like in step 7.
9. Switch your phone into developer mode

Now the deploying process should work without any trouble. If not try the steps (maybe with some variations) again. I don't know where the problem is, but the above steps worked for me. I don't know whether all steps are necessary, report back if you can leave one out. This solution doesn't helps permanently, sometimes the problem comes up again. I think don't unplug the phone while debugging, helps to let the problem occur less often.

Answer (score -2):

You simply need to swipe your phone to unlock it (also enter pin if any). Since the phone is locked you cannot deploy any app on it.