# Visual Studio Pro 2015: Error DEP6100

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I'm having issue on Visual Studio Pro 2015 when trying to debug (ARM Solution Platform selected) on a Windows 10 Mobile physical device on my desktop.

The physical device: Nokia Lumia 920 OS Build 10.0.10586.36 (Developer mode)  (device not in lock screen and is powered on)

My Desktop: Windows 10 Pro, Intel Core i5-4670K 8GB RAM 64-bit OS Build 10.0.10586.36 (Developer mode)

I do not have this issue on my laptop using the same Nokia Lumia 920.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
>   DeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.   App1
>
> Error      Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.    App1

So far I've tried restarting both devices and re-installing Visual Studio 2015.

EDIT: So after I've tried the proposed solution, this is what I got even for my emulator. Tried re-installing and repairing, nothing works.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '8BDF218D-FDBB-4A97-90F9-3AA33B559A92'.': DeviceException - The system cannot find the file specified.   App1
>
> Error      Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. The system cannot find the file specified. App1

Comment: Have you tried answers from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33473200/2681948)?

Comment: @Romasz, tried. Not sure why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve the emulator issue by **Installing a newer version of Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 mobile** from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive.

Next I'll try deleting the driver from device manager and if that fails, I'll restoring my device to factory defaults, enable developer mode, and try again to deploy on a physical device.

EDIT: As for the device issue, I **deleted the drivers from Device Manager** and now I'm able to deploy my apps onto the physical device.

[Lumia 920 Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ1qb.png)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is your project need to be deployed first, but may be Emulator 10.0.14393 can't work as good as you want. Following below step can help you.

1. Turn off Hyper-V
2. Device Manager: Uninstall Hyper-V driver
3. Restart
4. Download Emulator (Version 10.0.10586.11): https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=698769
5. Restart
6. Deploying project by Emlulator ver 10586
7. Deploying in higher emulator version or real device.

It was successful with me!

Comment: I did just 1. and 4. and worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: Definitely there's something very wrong with emulators 10.0.14393, there's no possible way to even recreate them after these steps. Only the 8.1 emulators are rebuilt after removal.

Answer (score 1):

Does the computer detect the device?
I get this same error when developing with my Windows 10 device and VS105, even though my device is detected by my computer. While I haven't been able to find a permanent solution, the following steps work for me:

- Shut down Visual Studio
- Unplug your device from your computer
- Turn Developer mode OFF on your device.
- Plug your device back in
- Start up visual studio.
- Try running Debug again on your device. It should now come up with another error relating to the fact you don't have developer mode turned on.
- Turn developer mode back ON on your device.
- Debug should now run.

If you unplug your device, you'll need to go through these steps again before VS can detect it.

EDIT: It might also be worth trying the top answer here: [How to develop windows 10 uwp on real device (mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473200/how-to-develop-windows-10-uwp-on-real-device-mobile)

Comment: My computer is able to File Explorer into the device.

I tried both your solution and the top answer in the edit, doesn't work.